# If we increase and decrease gravity periodically, what is the name of the resulting wave?

Tags: waves, gravity, newtonian-gravity, astrophysics

The gravitational waves, as in the case of merging black holes, expand like water ripples in spacetime (this is how they are depicted in general), and they affect everything in the vicinity, including light. Please correct me if I am wrong.

When we periodically increase and decrease the gravitational force on a specific object (e.g. by changing distance to the source of gravity), however, it is something different.

What do we call the latter case of periodicity in gravity? It is surely a kind of a wave with some equation, but does it have a specific name in physics?

*P.S. It is not an easy search on Google, as [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) or [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) dominate the results.*

Comment: Please clarify, "When we periodically increase and decrease the gravitational force on a specific object (e.g. by changing location)" -- if all you do is change your location, then that's simply called "motion" ;) how do you want to increase the gravitational force on an object, by moving another mass relative to it? Gravitational waves require acceleration of mass. Constant motion of mass does not emit gravitational waves.

Comment: A tidal wave, perhaps?

Comment: you might be interested in something like this:

https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/2102.08339/  1D accelerated motion of an object would be not unlike bremstrahlung.

Comment: @knzhou That comment would make an excellent crossword puzzle clue for gravitational waves XD

Comment: isn’t it called a periodic or it, like the Earth around the Sun?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a setup that I think implements your question.

Let's say we have a large mass, $M$, located at the origin. We also have a test probe with a small mass $m$ located a large distance $R$ away.

Now let's suppose we shake the mass $M$, so its position follows a sinusoidally varying pattern (but with an amplitude much less than $R$).

The shaking can be done in a way that there will some small time-varying quadrupole moment. This time-varying quadruopole moment can generate gravitational waves, which will cause $m$ to accelerate. The amplitude of the acceleration will fall off as $1/R$.

There is also another effect, which is that the acceleration due to the "static" Newtonian $1/R^2$ force law will change in time as $R$ changes. This effect is *much* smaller than the (already small) effect of gravitational waves, and is not really a wave phenomenon. I'm not sure if this effect has a name. It is usually not studied because it is small and not particularly interesting. I'd be tempted to call it a part of the time-varying non-radiative *near-field*. It is called "near-field" because the contribution of this acceleration relative to the acceleration due to gravitational radiation, becomes arbitrarily small at large $R$, so it is only important "near" the source; it is "time-varying" for obvious reasons. It is "part of" because the full solutions of GR near $M$ are very complicated and include much more than just the $1/R^2$ "Newtonian" part.

One way to try to articulate the difference between the near field and radiative field is as follows. Gravitational waves are a solution to Einstein's equations *in vacuum*, without any matter present. The leading $1/R$ part of the gravitational field can be written as a superposition of vacuum solutions *(to leading order in the metric perturbation)*. On the other hand, the near-field is only part of a solution to Einstein's equations with matter, it does not exist in vacuum. In the Newtonian limit, the differential equation to solve would be Poisson's equation, or in general it would be GR with some stress-energy. If there is no matter present, the solutions to GR permit gravitational waves, but not a force falling off as $1/R^2$.

There is a similar distinction between the radiative and near-fields in electromagnetism.

Comment: Thank you. I was considering big moves like orbiting of planets, but the idea of shaking is also cool. How do gravitational waves accelerate an object? Does the object feel it or is this an acceleration according to some other frame of reference?

Comment: @Xfce4 There are different words you can use to describe what's going on. Probably the most rigorous way (but opaque without some more math) is to say that the spacetime curvature changes such that distances and times between nearby points in spacetime oscillate. A more intuitive picture is that a gravitational wave causes a freely-falling ring of test particles to stretch in a particular way, there is a cool animation here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Gravwav.gif

Comment: @Xfce4 In that animation, a "plus-polarized" gravitational wave is traveling along the direction perpendicular to your screen, and causing the ring of test particles to stretch and squeeze in a way that depends on time.

Comment: Yes, but what I wonder is if the object would feel the acceleration or the bending of spacetime. To me it looks like light around a black hole would suggest that it is traveling a straight path, while it has an acceleration due to our frame of reference. Similarly, maybe the dots do not observe a change in their distance according to each other and not experience any acceleration.

Comment: @Xfce4 An individual particle in a gravitational field is freely falling, so by the equivalence principle it will just "feel" that it is in an inertial frame (in gravity "freely falling" is inertial, so we on Earth are not in an inertial frame). However the distances between nearby particles will change. If you put a ruler between two particles on the ring, the number of tick marks between particles will change. So the distance changes and is measurable (and now has been measured with LIGO and Virgo).

Comment: What if we were the particles on the ring? Would we be able to notice the change in distance between us? Would we observe no change in the distance but feel the inertia?

Comment: @Xfce4 You would feel like you were freely falling, but the distances you measured to nearby points was changing. It's like the expansion of the Universe. You don't expand yourself or feel yourself expanding, but you get further away from other points in the Universe.

Comment: Wow, right. It is considered that we do not change in size while the universe expands. To me this is quite weird because it implies the space extends just outside of us. The explanation is that the chemical (electromagnetic) and nuclear forces inside us prevent it. But for some reason I always depict that all other forces rest on gravity or spacetime so they must be affected too (instead of resisting it).  Phew.